# Making a Triacontagon in Python

Tags: python, polygon, shapes

I have code to make a triacontagon (30 sided polygon) but when i let it run, it only provides an answer in the shell and not an actual program. It may be due to what I put beside int, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

**the code**

```
import turtle

numberOfSides = int(input('30'))
lengthOfSide = int(input('5'))
exteriorAngle = 360/numberOfSides
for i in range(numberOfSides):
    turtle.forward(lengthOfSide)
    turtle.right(exteriorAngle)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what is happening, you are misunderstanding the use of [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

`input()` ask the user for input at runtime. Let say in the code you have `x = int(input("Please type number of sides: "))`, then the user is asked for input, typically to be typed in the terminal, and the input is saved in the variable `x`. The string argument of `input()` is shown in the terminal just before the user typing: it's intent is to provide information to the user on what he/she have to type.

In your case, if you want to draw a triacontagon you could just edit your code this way:

```
numberOfSides = 30
lengthOfSide = 5
```

You do not need `input()` to assign to a variable a known value.

But your code is more general, it can draw any regular polygon. To make it more clear, try to edit it this way:

```
numberOfSides = int(input("Please type number of sides: "))
lengthOfSide = int(input("Please type length of sides: "))
```

It will draw a regular polygon according to the numbers you give him each time you execute the code (if you type 4 and 10 for example, the code draws a square whose each side is of length 10).

Remember to add at the end of the script:

```
turtle.done()
```

otherwise the window is closed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually, it will be long, but it will be SO much easier.

Here is the code you should type:
By the way, this tricantagon won't look exactly like a tricantagon, more like a circle, but if you see the code, it is a tricantagon. 30 sides!!

```
from turtle import *
speed(1)
penup()
setpos(-250, 0)
down()
for i in range(72):
    fd(10)
    left(5)
```

Comment: This doesn't have 30 sides, it has 72.  Why should the OP type this code?

Comment: @cdlane have you ran the code? Also, if you do the math, it goes left 5 degrees. A circle is 360 degrees, and 72*5 is 360. Also, if you run the code, you will see that it has close to 30 spokes

Comment: Yes, I ran the code.  You just confirmed what I said, it has 72 sides, not 30.  But in your answer you wrote "but if you see the code, it is a tricantagon. 30 sides!!!"  I see the code.  72 sides.  Not a triacontagon.

Comment: @cdlane My mistake I mixed this up with a different question I answered